# How to sync counter via sockets on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, asyncsocket

I have a Application on a PC which displays time-information for a mp3 song that is played. I now need to display this time information within an iPad App. The counting timers for remaining time, player position and song length must be in sync between iPad an PC.

I thought about using a socket connection (AsyncSocket on iPad) to keep the counters in sync.

Is there a better way doing this? I don't want to run in the wrong direction...

Additional, it should be possible to have more than one iPad showing the Information in future. That's a "nice to have" feature...

I don't need ready to use code snippets, it's more a theoretical question. (if someone has a ready to use code snippet, that's also good for me :-) )

MadMaxApp

Comment: Did the job with a Socket-Connection! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i now used the AsyncSocket to solve the requirements. It works perfectly. Don't forget the handling of closing the socket connection if the app goes in background. Depending on the server the app is talking with, not closing the socket can lead to a problem in reconnecting.